# Dynamic generate ids for items in an adapter (not just a number)

Tags: android, kotlin

On StackOverflow we have many answers for setting a dynamic id for a view. Just assign a number and voilá.
I want to assign an id like we have in ids.xml file.

```
fun populate(item: RadioButtonItem, position: Int) {
    itemView.id = SomeFunctionToGenerateIDBasedOnName("name_id_$position")
}
```

I have an adapter that is populated by a dynamic list. And my testers need to get the id of an item in the adapter. They are using appium to locate the views.

I tried to use Reflection, transform string to int. No success.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not safe, because id collisions can always happen. Ask your QA's if you can use the contentDescription field instead, and then you can use whichever id you want.

Comment: Screens have only one adapter. Why isn't safe if I'm passing position as part of the name?

Comment: because the id is an integer. Even if you generate a random number (and then manipulate that number to add the position information), that number now becomes non-random